# RSA: Probalistic algorithm to compute $x$ from $y$ and $(n,e)$ with probability $\epsilon>0$ given set of weak ciphertexts?

Tags: encryption, rsa

Suppose there exists a set of ciphertexts $S \subset Z_n^*$ of size $\epsilon (p-1)(q-1) $ for $\epsilon>0$, that is easy to decrypt, i.e. there exist some algorithm $A_1 : \mathcal C \rightarrow \mathcal P \cup \{\text{void}\}$ that given ciphertext $y \in S$ and public key $(n,e)$ outputs correspoding plaintext $x$ and otherwise returns $\text{void}$.

I want to create a probalistic algorithm $A_2$ that given ciphertext $y$ and public key $(n,e)$ returns corresponding plaintext $x$ with probability at least $\epsilon$.

In the textbook a hint is given: Use $A_1$ as a subroutine and the RSA multiplicative property $$e_K(x_1x_2 \bmod n) = e_K(x_1)e_K(x_2) \bmod n$$

I've already proven that if $y\in Z_n \setminus Z_n^*$ then the secret key $(n,d)$ can be computed easily, which in turn yields the ciphertext $x$.

However, I'm stuck in the case $y\in Z_n^*$.

I've tried to consider how to split $y$ into prime factors $\prod_i p_i$, and then use the RSA multiplicative property, but this gets me nowhere.

Also, I've tried to consider picking plaintexts (or ciphertexts) at random, and then see if the product of their encryption their yields $y$.

Note:

For $y \in Z_n^*$, I cannot simply run $A_1$, because then the probability of returning $x$ would be $0$.

Comment: What type has $\epsilon$ ? Please note that It cannot be from $Z^*_n$, because on the modular multiplicative group there cannot be defined an order .

Comment: @Cryptostasis - Epsilon is a real number. I've corrected several typos.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d_k$ denote decryption and $x = d_K(y)$. I further assume that $\epsilon < 1$.
First note that $A_1$ calculates a *randomly chosen* cipher text $y$ with probability $\epsilon$.
But the task is to construct a probabilistic algorithm $A_2$ which decrypts a *fixed* cipher text $y$.
Therefore, proceed as follows:

1. choose a random $r \in Z^*_n$
2. calculate $y' = y* e_K(r)$
3. Use $A_1$ to decrypt $y'$ to $x'$
4. calculate $x = r^{-1}*x'$

This algorithm calculates the decryption of $y$ with probability $\epsilon$:
 - In step 2, $y'$ lands with probability $\epsilon$ in $S$
 - In step 3, the calculation yields
$$x'= d_k(y') = d_k(y*e_K(r)) = d_K(y)*d_K(e_K(r)) = d_K(y)*r = x*r$$

Comment: Are you sure about your argument for step 2? I mean, $e_K(r)$ is not guaranteed to be in ${Z_n}^*$ ?

Comment: Sure, $e_K$ maps  $Z_n^* \mapsto Z_n^*$

Comment: Ahh, yes, I just confused myself by thinking of an arbitrary cryptosystem, like AES...

Comment: Do you know what is done in practice if the ciphertext $y \in Z_n \setminus Z_n^*$? This would reveal the secret key?

Comment: If $n= p*q$ and you know any $y$ in $Z_n \setminus Z_n^*$, you can calculate $p  = \gcd(y, n)$.

Comment: So, if Alice is about to send $y \in Z_n \setminus Z_n^*$ to Bob she will stop, because such ciphertext sent over the channel would reveal the secret key to the adversary? What I'm asking is what is done to prevent such ciphertexts to be sent in practice?

Comment: @Shuzheng: in practice, what's passed to the textbook RSA functions ($x\mapsto x^d\bmod N$ and $x\mapsto x^e\bmod N$) is either produced by an appropriate padding function, thus has negligible chance to belong to the set $\mathbb Z_n \setminus\mathbb Z_n^*$ (thus the function's  result won't belong to this set); or is crafted by an adversary, which has no way to know any element in this set, with the exception of 0.